# Use sed replace with line number from variable

Tags: bash, sed

This is my `sed` command:

```
while ...;
do sed -r "${counter}s/^\S+ /$line /g" $in > $out;
..
..
done
```

Unfortunately this command isn't doing anything when called from within a bash script/loop. So I thought to check if the variables are being resolved the right way:

```
do echo ´sed -r "${counter}s/^\S+/$line/g" $in > $out´;
```

which printed this to the console:

```
sed -r <line number>/^\S+/<replace pattern>/g <infile> > <outfile>
```

When executing this very command (without the ´) from the console, I get this:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated s' command
```

I guess this is because the `'` are missing around the pattern.

So how do I combine double (for resolving variables in sed command) and single (for completing the search/replace pattern) quotation marks when calling this from a bash script?

Comment: how could it possibly work? i dont see any input at all, and it looks like youre calling `sed` to work a single line at a time. if thats the case then `$counter` wont ever work for any line at all but line 1. you really shouldn't loop like that - its spidery and wasteful. think in terms of a chain instead of in terms of a home base. if you do: `while gen ouput; do :; done | sed 's/edit/the_whole_stream/'` you'll be a lot better off.

Comment: $counter is being raised after the sed command. So that is one working. Yes, I'm want to call sed for each line, because I got a file A and file B. The beginning of line in file B should be replaced with the beginning of line in file A.Those chars differ in each line.

Comment: awk or perl are better tools for doing that.

Comment: Is there `/` or `\n` in `$line` variable? Any way try to execute `sed -r "<line number>/^\S+/<replace pattern>/g" <infile> > <outfile>` for testing purpose. Is it doing what you wants?

Comment: Hi, no such thing in $line. The command itself with expanded/resolved variables works fine. Calling the mentioned command with the line number from a variable isn't working so far.

Comment: Instead of trying to echo the command, try adding `set -x` at the top of your script. Bash will then automatically echo every command after variable substitution.

Comment: awesome, `set -x` is what I was looking for! This output lacks the **> <outfile>** part. This suggests the changes are not written to the output file. Is this a `set -x` thing?

Comment: it depends on your shell, but most shells do not include redirections in `set -x` output at all.

Answer (score -1):

Well, that is strange. The redirect to the output file didn't happen, at least not with the expected replacements. A `cp <infile> <outfile>` with the following sed replace command **inplace** works like a charm....

Thanks for your help!